# Customs officer stamp for one year

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, passport-stamps

My mom, an Indian citizen, came to the USA in May 2017 to visit me. The Immigration officer wrote May xx, 2018 on her passport in the little stamp box. Normally you cannot stay in the US longer than 6 months. Does this mean she can stay for a year?

If possible please provide a link to the website if you find the answer!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have your checked her admission status (i-94, I think?) for a definitive admitted-until date?

Comment: [8 CFR 214.2(b)](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-11261/0-0-0-17197/0-0-0-17437.html) says that B visitors can be admitted for up to a year.

Answer (score 3):

The regulations for a B-1/B-2 visitor, [at 8 CFR 214.2(b)](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-11261/0-0-0-17197/0-0-0-17437.html), allow admissions of up to one year to be granted in that status. Six months is more of a minimum for a B-2 entry, if your mom asked for a long stay and the officer thought your mom seemed reliable and the purpose of the visit reasonable then the officer has the discretion to grant a stay longer than six months. If your mom requested to stay for a full 6 months the longer stay might have been granted to allow her some flexibility to avoid an inadvertent overstay or an extension request should her plans need to change.

As the comment points out it might be good to give your mom's details to [the CBP I-94 website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home) to make sure that the leave-by date on the CBP's record of her current I-94 matches what is in her passport. If it does she can legally stay until that date. The only other thing to consider before having her do that, however, is that staying significantly longer than she requested when she entered, if the officer noted that in her record (which seems likely for an exceptionally long stay), can cause them to have a more negative view of your mom's reliability on subsequent entries, so if you expect your mom to visit again soon you can minimize the potential for trouble the next time she comes by having her stick to more-or-less the trip she told them she was taking this time.

Comment: Rather than a minimum, six months is the *default.*  A visitor can certainly be admitted for a shorter period, but that shorter period has to be approved by a supervisor.